# Tomcat: No Catalina logs for server error

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I am using apache-tomcat-6.0.20, and am only seeing access logs in my logs directory.

My logging.properties file has all categories set to INFO.

I've removed my error page and when the exception is thrown I just see a 404 page. There are no relevant errors in my application log.

How do I set up this logging?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this myself, was missing these 2 properties in my Eclipse Server's VM Arguments:

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\whatever\conf\logging.properties"
```